# PowerShell script in Pentaho

Tags: powershell, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I would like to use a PowerShell script to count lines in a text file. I use this code:

```
Set-Location -Path D:\
$measure = Get-Content b27.csv | Measure-Object 
$lines = $measure.Count
echo "line count is: ${lines}"
```

However, I have got error. I think there is something missing to tell pentaho to execute the PowerShell script

After that I try to add this code

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass [D:\]
call Set-Location -Path D:\
call $measure = Get-Content b27.csv | Measure-Object 
call  $lines = $measure.Count
call echo "line count is: ${lines}"
```

but it doesn't work.

Please find the error as below:

[image: error message]

Comment: Please post the error message you receive

Comment: Your code is PowerShell, but you're invoking a batch file (`.bat`). Rename the file to `.ps1` and remove the line `powershell.exe ...` from it. If that doesn't work you may need to invoke the PowerShell script from a batch file: `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\path\to\your.ps1"`.

Comment: I have already edited please find in the first comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use the "Get Files Rows Count" step? It would be cross platform that way.